# RewriteRule в .htaccess правильный ли синтаксис

Tags: .htaccess

Есть файл `sitemap.php`, который формирует группу файлов `sitemap`. Так же в нем формируются ссылки вида `sitemap_index0.xml`, `sitemap_product0.xml` и т.д.

По задумке, мне нужно передать два параметра( `GET` ), например `type=product` и `limit=0`.
Чтобы отобразить содержимое, например, `sitemap_product0.xml`, в `.htaccess` добавляю:

```
RewriteRule sitemap_(.*)([0-9]+)\.xml$ core/sitemap.php?type=$1&limit=$2 [L]
```

На локалке работает, на хосте нет( `404` ).
Что-то я сделал неправильно, не пойму только что именно.

Comment: Попробуйте указать абсолютный путь к `core/sitemap.php`. А вообще, в логах Apache должна быть ошибка 404 с указанием пути, куда пытается скрипт обратиться. Ну и проверьте, на всякий случай, существование самого файла

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Буду пробовать. Сам синтаксис RewriteRule, приведенной строки, не вызывает сомнений? Я как бы не встречал в примерах две смежные группы символов не разделенных "слешем", и плюс еще "нижнее подчеркивание" в URL.

Comment: Нет, проблем не вижу, кроме того, что у вас перед цифрами из-за формулировки `(.*)` может ничего не быть и `sitemap_0.xml` удовлетворяет условию. Если это неверно, то вместо `(.*)` следует использовать `(.+)`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина подобного поведения может крыться в следующем:

- Указан относительный, а не абсолютный путь к необходимому файлу
- Файл не существует

Следовательно, чтобы исправить эту ошибку, нужно:

- Проверить формирование пути к файлу в логах Apache
- Указать абсолютный путь к `core/sitemap.php`
- Проверить существование файла по указанному пути

В синтаксисе я не вижу ошибок.
Единственное замечание: регулярному выражению `sitemap_(.*)([0-9]+)\.xml$` соответствуют не только подобные карты сайта:

- `sitemap_index0.xml`
- `sitemap_product0.xml`

Но и:

- `sitemap_0.xml`
- `sitemap_1.xml`

Если такое поведение нежелательно, то следует исправить `(.*)` на `(.+)`, получив в итоге такое регулярное выражение: `sitemap_(.+)([0-9]+)\.xml$`.